# How to apply a function on every possible combination of two columns in two matrices in R

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I have two matrices each has 300 columns; `M1` and `M2` I am applying a simple `ifelse` function on them as following:

```
result<-ifelse(M1[-nrow(M1),]<M2[-nrow(M2),],1,4)


tail(result)


                    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17
2017-06-26 04:00:00  4  1  1  4  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
2017-06-26 05:00:00  4  1  1  1  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
2017-06-26 06:00:00  4  1  1  1  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
2017-06-26 07:00:00  4  1  1  1  4  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
2017-06-26 08:00:00  4  1  1  1  1  4  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
2017-06-26 09:00:00  4  1  1  1  1  1  4  4  4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```

In this case the `ifelse` function applied on every column in `M1` with it's matching column in `M2`

How can I apply the `ifelse` function on every possible combination of columns in `M1` and `M2` and save the results into one big matrix (90000 columns in this case) or list of matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `expand.grid` to get a cartesian product of the column indices would help.

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
m2 <- matrix(4:12, ncol=3)
g <- expand.grid(1:nrow(m1), 1:ncol(m2))
ans <- ifelse(m1[, g[, 1]] < m2[, g[, 2]], 1, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is simple and does the job. Small thing, I think in my case it should be `g <- expand.grid(1:ncol(m1), 1:ncol(m2))` instead of `1:nrow(m1)` since I am interested to make the test on every combination of columns not columns against the rows of the other matrix.

when I applied the code on the whole data (including 3700 rows), my computer froze and I had to restart it. when I did the same on only 10 rows, it worked. any suggestions how can I make it applicable on the whole data set?

Comment: @aRo From your description, I'm guessing your computer probably froze because it ran out of memory when running the commands (R does things in-memory). If so, try the following

1) bigmemory to store some of your data on disk https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html
2) Use a for-loop to build compare each index and save it into a matrix instead of doing things in one shot
3) Get more ram